# Powershell profile, dynamic prompt and ansi color escape codes being reset after git has executed

Tags: powershell

I am trying to duplicate my [cmder](http://cmder.net/) dynamic prompt inside Powershell.

This dynamic prompt uses a combination of some specific unicode characters and background and foreground colors to produce a prompt that can contain items, such as:

- Current directory (white on blue)
- Current git branch (black on green)
- Ahead/behind (black on yellow or white)
- Special status (merge, rebase, etc. - black on red)

The cmder prompt works wonders, and I've managed to reproduce most, if not all, of it using a `Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1` script with code.

However, after running some git commands, like `git pull`, the powershell prompt becomes messed up. The symptoms are that handling of those escape codes are suddenly turned off. This does not happen if I only use `cmder`.

Example:

[image: cmder vs powershell]

The top `git lg` (git log on one line, decorated) command is running from cmder, notice that the prompt comes back with colors.

Then I switch to powershell right above the middle, notice I got the same looking prompt there, only this is produced from the powershell profile script.

However, after running `git lg` once again, only now from Powershell, the handling of the escape codes are disabled and the prompt now becomes totally messed up.

My question is:

> Is there anything I can do in the powershell profile to enable this before producing the prompt, or to prevent this from happening?

Here is a very simple powershell profile file:

```
function prompt {
    "" + [char]0x001b + "[39;44mTEST" + [char]0x001b + "[0m" + [char]0x000a + "> "
}
```

Simply drop this into a file named as:

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

*(make sure to make a backup of the file if it already exists!)*

Then start Powershell and you should be able to reproduce this:

[image: powershell ansi codes messed up]

Notice that last line before the prompt there contains the escape codes verbatim.

Things I've tried:

- Outputting [ESC c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code): Resets the device to its original state. (no apparent effect or change)
- Running Powershell directly (not from within cmder), this works exactly the same as above, only the Windows has different initial colors, such as a blue background. The coloring of my prompt seems to work fine, the special characters doesn't though but that's to be expected (the branch symbol and that triangle), but after `git lg`, still messed up.

Comment: Is the problem reproducible if you start PowerShell from the Windows Start Menu instead of from a CMD prompt?

Comment: Yes it is, only the escape character became a little box instead of that box with a question mark, but other than that it turned out the same way.

Comment: Have you seen the [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) module? I think it covers everything you're using cmder for..

Comment: It looks like somehow `git` is disabling `cmder` and using the default `conhost`, which does not support ANSI color. Both `CMD` and PowerShell (non-ISE) use `conhost` as the console handler, in the absence of any other handler.

Comment: Yes, but please note that if I run Powershell from the start menu, from CMD, or from within cmder, the ansi colors do work, up until I execute some of the git commands. This is equal for all the ways I've tried to start Powershell.

Comment: Also, if I start cmder, and run powershell within it, run one of the git commands that reproduces the behavior described above, then exit back to cmder, cmder keeps working.

Comment: Agh, I've found one thing that fixes it, I turned on ConEmuHk injection inside cmder, this made the behavior stop, [but I can't simply enable this](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1158) because this makes bash from within git fail with stack overflow.

Comment: However, this only fixes the problem within cmder, if I run it from cmd, or just run powershell directly, the problem still appears as described.

Comment: What exact windows version do you use? In context of supporting WSL the console host has undergone several changes lastly.  Also I think git outputs some text to the errorstream not standardin.